# How to order specific datetime like values

Tags: r, datetime

I would like to sort date in decreasing order.

Currently I'm using this approach, but it does not always work.

```
data.frame(zoo(data order.by=as.POSIXct(data$date)), row.names=NULL)
```

Column `date` contains these values:

```
x <- "2261 2017-04-14 08:42:17.287374
      2262 2017-04-14 08:44:30.683207
      2263 2017-04-14 08:46:43.611042
      2264 2017-04-14 08:48:56.991276
      2265 2017-04-14 11:24:26.808124
      2266 2017-04-14 08:51:09.794308
      2267 2017-04-14 08:54:06.324218
      2268 2017-04-14 08:56:19.610852"

d <- read.table(text=x, header=F)
```

Please note that the the `V1` is the `rownames` in data.frame and and `V2` and `V3` is not separated but one column, named `date`.

So this is closer what I have got:

```
data <- data.frame(date=paste(d$V1,d$V2, sep=" "))
```

Comment: See [mcve] for how to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: well, I provided data and description together with current solution, not sure what else is missing...provided `read-in` solution...

Comment: `data$date` as defined in the question is a factor and its first element is `2261 2017-04-14` which is not valid for converting to POSIXct.   `z <-
 read.zoo(text = x, index = 2:3, tz = "")` would read `x` into a zoo object `z` and `fortify.zoo(z)` would convert that to a data.frame.

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- "2261 2017-04-14 08:42:17.287374
      2262 2017-04-14 08:44:30.683207
2263 2017-04-14 08:46:43.611042
2264 2017-04-14 08:48:56.991276
2265 2017-04-14 11:24:26.808124
2266 2017-04-14 08:51:09.794308
2267 2017-04-14 08:54:06.324218
2268 2017-04-14 08:56:19.610852"

d <- read.table(text=x, header=F)

rnames = d$V1

d$Date = paste(d$V2, d$V3)
d$Date = as.POSIXct(d$Date)

rownames(d) = rnames


d = d[order(d$Date, decreasing = TRUE), ]
d = d["Date"]

> d
                    Date
2265 2017-04-14 11:24:26
2268 2017-04-14 08:56:19
2267 2017-04-14 08:54:06
2266 2017-04-14 08:51:09
2264 2017-04-14 08:48:56
2263 2017-04-14 08:46:43
2262 2017-04-14 08:44:30
2261 2017-04-14 08:42:17
```